# I use setOnMouseEntered and there is some exception

Tags: java, javafx

I write a code that use On Mouse Entered and I do nothing on method. And there is the exception when mouse entered on pane what I set action.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventQueue.fire(EventQueue.java:48)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.handleEnterExit(Scene.java:3676)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3742)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

Following code is what I want to make act.

```
  @FXML
void mouseMovedOnPane(ActionEvent event) {
 ButtonPane.setVisible(true);
}
```

The method name "mouseMovedOnPane" is what is set on scene-builder  "On Mouse Entered".

How can I make code act what I want?

I'm Korean live in Korea and there is some error about using grammar or word selecting.
I want you understand about it.

Sorry.
I append some more question.

In the code what I wrote, the method ButtonPane.setVisible(true) is also not doing any action. What is the fault?

Comment: Ok. Thanks I edited it

Comment: Thanks for notify me

Comment: This is probably the wrong parameter type like said. In a Mouse entered event, I would guess this would be a MouseEvent parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `IllegalArgumentException` with the text as `argument type mismatch`. I don't know anything about java fx, but this probably means that you are using the wrong signature in your callback; you shouldn't take an `ActionEvent` but something else. Check that.

A very rapid google search seems to indicate that you might need a `MouseEvent`.

Comment: Yes It's true It need MouseEvent in parameter like         
void mouseMovedOnPane(MouseEvent event) {
 ButtonPane.setVisible(true);
}. It's work properly